# interesting behaviour of upper bounded java wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have example:

```
public static <T extends Number> void doJob(List<T> pr,List<? extends Number> en,T tel){
            // 
            System.out.println(pr.get(0).intValue());

   }

List<? extends Integer> intList=new ArrayList<>();
Integer inval=200;
List<Integer> intList3=new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
doJob(intList3,intList,inval);//it is allowed 
intList=intList3;
doJob(intList,intList,intList.get(0));//IT IS FORBIDDEN
```

> Why does compiler forbid call of
>   **doJob(intList,intList,intList.get(0));** even intList in fact is
>   List type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that is because, Ultimately you are doing:

```
List<? extends Integer> ls = new ArrayList<Integer>();
doJob(ls,ls,ls.get(0));
```

So ls (or your `intList`) is actually a List of an unknown type. But what you do know, is that this unknown type extends `Number`.

So when you call `doJob`, `T` in `doJob` becomes this unknown type. Your second argument matches as `List<? extends Number>` is a super type to `List<? extends Integer>`.

As per your third argument, we already know that `T` is unknown and you try passing `intList.get(0)`. Now `intList.get` will return `? extends Integer`, i.e. another unknown type (which extends Integer). So you try passing an unknown type to a method which expects an unknown type. And two unknown's cant be guaranteed to be equal. Hence the error.

Comment: it seems You are right, because i tried to define another method  : public static <T extends Number> void doanotherJob(List<T> pr,List<? extends Number> en) . And in this case it works with doanotherJob(intList,intList); Thanks.

Comment: Thank You. But You need to wait little before i get 15 score reputation to be able  upvote. :-(